# Concerning the U.S Visa Waiver Program and job hunting

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas, new-zealand

If I enter the U.S under the Visa Waiver program, can I search for a job and make connections, so long as I *apply* for said job once I return to my home country? Or am I best to apply for a B-1/B-2 visa, which I can then transfer to a H2B working visa whilst I'm in the States? 
Note that my *main* purpose of visiting the U.S would be to visit my girlfriend.

Comment: The answers to that question concerned Australian citizens, who are eligible for E-3 visas; not available to New Zealand citizens

Comment: To expand on @pnuts's comment, any activity that is permitted under a B-1 or B-2 visa is permitted under the VWP (in particular, B-1 activities are permitted for those admitted in WB status, and B-2 activities for those admitted in WT status).  As you note, though, a B visa would allow you to apply to change to H-1B.  You're probably better off going back home for your H-1B, though, rather than changing status in the US.  If you ask this question on [Expatriates.SE] you'll likely get a response from one of the people there who are familiar with these procedures.

Comment: @pnuts In theory, I suppose one could get in trouble for business activities in WT status, but in practice, I doubt it would be likely to come up.

Comment: You can _apply_ for jobs in VWP status too, _interview_ for them, and even _accept_ any offers you might get at the interview. But you can't actually _start work_ on the job until you have returned home and gotten a work visa.